# Is Tensorflow shape just for convenience?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

It's pretty neat that Tensorflow allows you to define and do math on arbitrary tensors, but for supervised learning applications, is there any reason you would want to define your inputs and outputs as anything other than a vector?

Are there any common reasons for needing the extra abstraction that tensors allow?

Comment: What if you have a stack of images as data?

Comment: I was imagining just having a one dimensional array of pixel values.  As far as neural networks and back propagation, wouldn't this be equivalent to taking in a matrix?

Comment: You could do all of the arithmetic to work out which pixels are one row down, two rows down, $n$ rows down... but wouldn't it just be easier to slide your convolutional filter over the source image instead? I mean, yeah, you can map back-and-forth between the two, but I'd rather work with a stack of images than unspool them and then labor to un-unspool them again when I want to retain the image's spatially-organized properties. Tensorflow is built around this particular convenience especially.

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't really thought about convolutional nets.

Comment: There is math, high-level code, and lower-level implementation. What is "best" can easily vary between the three. (For example [Data locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) is a common concern in implementing lower level algorithms.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, we use tensors for images. Images in tensorflow are defined by a 4d tensor with its shape as follows:

batch_size x height x width x no_of_channels

where batch_size is the number of images that we have in our dataset. The number of channels refer to RGB

Therefore, tensors are a great way to represent images.